# How to implement priority queue with a custom class in python?

Tags: python

I am from java background, I need to something like this

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    int score;
    ArrayList<Integer> arr;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o2) {
        return score != o2.score ? score - o2.score : arr.size() - o2.arr.size();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Item> p = new PriorityQueue<Item>();

    }
}
```

So I have a class which has two variable, score and list. There is a calculation for natural ordering for also too.

Could somebody please tell me how to do it python? heapq does not work for me, because my score function checks score on the basis of two variables not one.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck because an implementation [already exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue).

Make sure to follow the regular structuring of entries and attach the priority to all entries inserted into the queue using a tuple of the form `(priorities_tuple, entry)`.

An example:

```
import Queue
import random
pq = Queue.PriorityQueue()
todos = ["eat", "sleep", "python"]
# obvously replace random with your 
todos_with_priorities = [((random.random(),), e) for e in todos]
for e in todos:
    pq.put(e)
```

Consume the queue like so:

```
priorities, item = pq.get()
```

To form more and more complex priorities add more members to the tuple structure. In your case the tuple should be something like: `((e.score, len(e.arr)), e)`.

Comment: But if my data is in the form of tuple, I can't handle the tite breaking unlike comareTo above?

Comment: @Dude look at the edit. Tell me if you're missing something.

Comment: The `PriorityQueue` in `Queue` comes with extra baggage (it's thread safe). If performance is an issue then I'd recommend creating a class wrapper for the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module.